# How to use boto3 to create an AMI from an Amazon EBS Snapshot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

While creating an image (AMI) in AWS using boto3 lib, providing the following parameters:

```
ec2.create_image(Name=name, BlockDeviceMappings=[{'DeviceName':device_name,'Ebs':{'SnapshotId':snapshot_id, 'DeleteOnTermination': delete_on_term,
            'VolumeSize':10, 'VolumeType':'gp2'}}])
```

I'm getting this error: `Missing required parameter in input: "InstanceId"`
But when I create an image from the User Interface, no Instance Id is required.

In the picture below, you can see that I can create the image from 'Snapshots' page, without specifying instance Id.

[image]

Is anyone aware of a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this function register_image to create image from snapshots

```
response = client.register_image(
    ImageLocation='string',
    Architecture='i386'|'x86_64'|'arm64',
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': 'string',
            'VirtualName': 'string',
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True|False,
                'Iops': 123,
                'SnapshotId': 'string',
                'VolumeSize': 123,
                'VolumeType': 'standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1',
                'Encrypted': True|False,
                'KmsKeyId': 'string'
            },
            'NoDevice': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Description='string',
    DryRun=True|False,
    EnaSupport=True|False,
    KernelId='string',
    Name='string',
    BillingProducts=[
        'string',
    ],
    RamdiskId='string',
    RootDeviceName='string',
    SriovNetSupport='string',
    VirtualizationType='string'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_image

"InstanceId" is required - It has to contain the instance Id which you are trying to create the image off of.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that too, but I was wondering since we are able to perform that functionality in the UI, is there a workaround in boto3 to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an image from console, you select the select the instance and select the create image option. So console uses the selected instance id to be passed for creating the image.

When you need to create an image using boto3, you need to tell the API for which instance you are creating the image, hence you need to pass in the parameters. Try this

```
ec2.create_image(instance_id=yourInstanceId, Name=name, BlockDeviceMappings=[{'DeviceName':device_name,'Ebs':{'SnapshotId':snapshot_id, 'DeleteOnTermination': delete_on_term,
            'VolumeSize':10, 'VolumeType':'gp2'}}])
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted the screenshot in my post to show that I'm not specifying instance id and that screen is not in the instances page.

Comment: @M You are creating a snapshot from a volume attached to your instance. Snapshots are different from AMIs. Snapshots are the copy of the a disk volume, while AMI is the whole machine image. And I said before, console you reach tot the point of making an image or snapshot selecting the volume, instance to starrt with.